# Link is not working in IE 10, 11

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

The about us page link is not working in my website (IE only). all aother browsers are redirecting to the page. I have dropdown in my about us link also have link to about us .
How can i solve that?

here is my code

```
<ul id="navigation-top" class="navigation-top" >
    <li id="menu-item-301" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-301">
        <a href="about_us.php" id="aboutus_link">About Us</a>
        <div class="drop" id="drop_about">
            <ul class="sub-menu" id="about_drop">
                <li id="menu-item-1722" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1722">
                    <a href="about_us.php#company" alt="company_tab">Company</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-1722" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1722">
                    <a href="about_us.php#founders" alt="founders_tab">The Founders</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-1722" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1722">
                    <a href="about_us.php#team" alt="team_tab">Team</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-1722" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1722">
                    <a href="about_us.php#accolades" alt="accolades_tab">Accolades</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-1722" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1722">
                    <a href="about_us.php#careers" alt="careers_tab">Careers</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-1722" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1722">
                    <a href="about_us.php#philosophy" alt="philosophy_tab">Philosophy</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here is [Live demo](http://www.flutura.com/flutura-trial/)

Comment: The link works for me in IE9

Comment: They work for me (IE11)

Comment: I didn't get you brother. Working example means?

Comment: Use some sample codes rather pointing to a website.

Comment: I am using IE 11 but i can't access about us page from home page. but my dropdown menu's are working